# Conditional typing based on pointer or value type

Tags: c++

I wonder if I can do some conditional typing based on if a template parameter is a pointer or not?

So for instance I want the get method below to return `T` itself if it is a pointer(i.e. T*). Or `T*` if is not a pointer (i.e. T).

```
template<typename T>
class MyContainer {
    T get(); // If T is a pointer
    T* get(); // If T is not a pointer
}
```

Comment: how about `std::remove_pointer_t<T> * get();`

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis it is almost the same, but it doesn't help me that much. I think it is basing the overload resolution based on the parameter. My `get()` method doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: `I think it is basing the overload resolution based on the parameter.` - no, it is not.

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis you are right it was probably a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Just condition if it's a pointer and if not:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T>
class MyContainer {
    std::conditional_t<std::is_pointer<T>::value, T, T*> get();
};
```